# Intellisense Finds Header But Compiler Doesn't

Tags: windows

I'm trying to build this example pipe client: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592(v=vs.85).aspx

I have the code inside a new vc++ console project in Visual Studio 2017. I know that I have installed the windows 8.1 SDK and am targeting it in my project settings.

Intellisense can find the typedef for HANDLE. When I try to compile, I get undeclared identifier, which tells me the compiler is not finding the same typedef, which should be included and definitely exists on my system.
[image]

Comment: I'm going for a full visual studio reinstall.

Comment: I uninstalled then reinstalled and I still get compiler errors.

Comment: Oh ****. You need to #include <windows.h> BEFORE #include "stdafx.h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code looked like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    HANDLE x;
}
```

i changed it to, and now it compiles:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE x;
}
```